# Using Fabric to deploy current git branch to heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku, fabric

I'd like to shorten the process of deploying to Heroku (i.e. a git push)

I use git-flow to organise my codebase - so typically the process would be:

1. start a new feature branch
2. Do the coding
3. Push this branch up to my dev heroku instance - `git push develop feature/somefeature:master`)
4. Merge into the develop branch
5. Create a new release branch
6. Push this to the production heroku instance - `git push production release/1.2.3:master`

What I'd like to do is be able to run a Fab command like:

`fab dev_deploy`

which would just deploy whatever the current working branch is to my dev instance

and

`fab prod_deploy`

which would do the same but push to the production instance.
I could include some sanity checks here to make sure I'm inside a release branch etc.

my fab commands would do other things (like push static assets up to the right S3 bucket etc, run south migrate commands and so on)

So all I really want to know is how to get the current working branch as a variable inside fabric...!?

Thanks,

Guy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK - a bit more digging got me this:

```
from fabric.api import local
my_branch = local('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD', capture=True)
```

which does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
my_branch = subprocess.check_output(['git','branch'])
```

or:

```
from fabric.api import local
my_branch = local('git branch')
```

Comment: These both run the regular 'git branch' command - which returns a list of local branches with the current one denoted with an asterix - is there no command that just gets the current branch for processing afterwards? or would I have to get this list and use a bit of regex to get the current branch.

Comment: Regex or something like `branches.split('*')` or however you prefer to slice up strings :)